# Add text after end line between N lines in a file with SED

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, replace

I have this issue trying to add this text ‘cd directory2/‘ to a file between lines 1 to 15. What I tried so far is:

`sed -ni '1,15p s/$/\ cd\ available\//g' myfile`

But I’m having this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: extra characters after command`.
In order to explain a little better the command:

- -ni —> Are the options of sed
- 1,15p —> Specified the lines from 1 to 15
- s/$/\ cd\ available//g’ —> The ’s’ is for substitution, the ‘$’ for search the end of a line, next I have my pattern to add and finally the ‘g’ option is for substitute without asking.

The files **looks** like this:

```
mget -p directory1/file1.csv
mget -p directory1/file2.csv
mget -p directory1/file3.csv
mget -p directory1/file4.txt
mget -p directory4/fileab.csv
mget -p directory4/fileabc.txt
```

And the **expected output** is:

```
mget -p directory1/file1.csv cd directory2/
mget -p directory1/file2.csv cd directory2/
mget -p directory1/file3.csv cd directory2/
mget -p directory1/file4.txt cd directory2/
mget -p directory4/fileab.csv
mget -p directory4/fileabc.txt
```

It's important to clarify that myfile has more content. So after the modification all the text that are in line 16 and more has to exist and not dissapear.

Comment: You can add the `p` at the end instead of adding it after the range `sed -ni '1,15 s/$/\ cd\ available\//g;p' myfile`

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird It's works like that ! Can you explain me why is neccesary to put a semicolon between g and p ?
I edit the question because I find a issue after the modification

Comment: You don't really need it, but the current answer is a better option. If you omit the `-n` to suppress the standard output of lines you don't have to explicitly print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1,15s/$/ cd directory2\//' file
```

In the range 1 to 15, append  `cd directory2/` only.